# LWC data table row action delete using refreshApex not updating table

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, developer

I have a row action delete function in a LWC data table. The delete works, but the issue is that the refreshApex() is not updating the table and the user needs to manually refresh the entire page. I have made sure that I am using (response) and that it is being set to a property that will be passed to the return statement of the refreshApex() inside of the then(). Any help will be appreciated.

```
    refreshTable;

    @wire(getFinHold, { fhId: '$recordId' }) dataTH(response)
    {
        this.refreshTable = response;
        const { data, error } = response

        if (data) 
        {
            this.dataTH = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        }
        else if (error)
        {
            this.error = error;
            this.dataTH = undefined;
            console.log(error);
        }
    }



 case 'delete':
                    this.recordId = event.target.value;
                    deleteRecord(row.Id)
                        .then(() => {
                            const toastrEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: 'Success',
                                message: 'Record deleted',
                                varient: 'success',
                            });

                            this.dispatchEvent(toastrEvent);
                            return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);                        
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            this.dispatchEvent(
                                new ShowToastEvent({
                                    title: 'Error',
                                    message: error.message,
                                    varient: 'error'
                                })
                            );
                        });
```